# Open PDF from C++ on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, pdf

I was looking for a way to just open a PDF file in a C++ program.
 I am coding for OSX, i know for Windows we can use a ShellExecute(), but i want to find a way to do it in OSX. 
I just want to show the PDF to the user, nothing else.

Comment: So your real question is: How can I start a process with parameters on Mac OS X?

Comment: possible duplicate of [open pdf in a C++ program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174460/open-pdf-in-a-c-program)

Comment: The other question was removed, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
system("open mypdf.pdf");
```

Where mypdf.pdf is the path to the file.

Comment: just that? lol thanks this almost like shellexecute in windows my regards